# Find the sum of finite series complex numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I've been asked to calculate the following complex number:

$\sum_{k=1}^{19} (1+i)^{k}$

I couldn't find much theory about it but I know we can obtain it by using the geometrical progression given by:

$1+z+z^2+ ... + z^{n}= \frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z}$

I wonder how can I proceed from here. I'm kinda lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to use the polar form of $z=1+i$, which is
$$z = \sqrt{2}\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{4}+i \sin \frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$
Then, by Moivre's formula:
$$z^n = \sqrt{2}^n \cdot \left(\cos\frac{n\pi}{4}+i \sin \frac{n\pi}{4}\right)$$
Hence $z+z^2+\ldots+z^{19}$ is equal to
$$\frac{z^{20}-1}{z-1}-1 = \frac{2^{10}\left(\cos 5\pi+i \sin5\pi\right)-1}{i}-1 = i\cdot (2^{10}+1)-1$$